# Can we use Tabpy to show visualizations generated from Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, tabpy, scatterplot3d

I created a 3D scatter plot using Plotly. I want to use tableau to visualize the plot so that it can be updated in realtime as data gets updated?
Can we use Tabpy to show visualizations generated from Plotly?

As per my knowledge, Tabpy script can work only when return type is real, int or string. If my script return as figure will it work?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not work with visualization. As you mentioned it only return values.